# Corda Settlement Example

Tags: kotlin, corda

Is there a working code example of settlements in Corda as explained in below video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glTWteHdJy0

I see there is an `Obligations.kt` file in `corda-master`. Can someone please guide me to a working example for same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily for you - the work that was explained in the video you posted was actually open sourced, so feel free to have a look here:

https://github.com/project-ubin/ubin-corda

Also, I wrote a simple obligation app that demonstrates how you can issue, transfer and settle obligations. This might be a better place to start than the project ubin source code. See below:

- **Obligation state:** https://github.com/roger3cev/obligation-cordapp/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/Obligation.kt
- **Obligation contract:** https://github.com/roger3cev/obligation-cordapp/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/ObligationContract.kt
- **Issue obligation:** https://github.com/roger3cev/obligation-cordapp/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/IssueObligation.kt
- **Settle obligation:** https://github.com/roger3cev/obligation-cordapp/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/SettleObligation.kt

Comment: No worries  - enjoy!